# storing a value, when closing flash movie

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using a timer in my flash movie. When I close the flash movie, I want to store the last `currentCount` value. Is there any predefined option available in as3.0. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `SharedObject` class u can achieve that.

refer the below link.

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using flash cookies? [how to use flash cookies in AS3](http://carroarmato0.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/as3-how-to-use-flash-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

If this movie is online you could set and read cookies via php or asp. Create some php script to store and retrieve cookie values and then call it from actionscript.